# How to query with 'OR' Operation in where object using find-options API in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I want find results in my repo where firstname is like 'john' **OR** lastname is like 'doe'
but findOptions where clause treat it as AND.

What I tried :

```
let results = await userRepo.find({
  where : {
    firstname : Like('%John%'),
    lastname : Like('%Doe%'),
  }
});
```

What I expect of this :

```
let results = await userRepo.find({
  where : {
    firstname : Like('%John%'),
    lastname : Or(Like('%Doe%')),
  }
});
```

Any help on how can I use **OR** within where object?

Comment: Did you mean "findOptions where clause treat it as AND"?

Comment: yes thanks, I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible to use OR clause using the simple typeorm .find() options as described in TypeORM [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md).

To query with OR operator you'll need to use an array of conditions instead of an object.

```
    let results = await userRepo.find({
        where: [
            { firstname: Like('%John%') },
            { lastname: Like('%Doe%') }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Yeah. I get it. It was published way after time my question was published. Thanks anyways. Here's the reference commit : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/commit/69a752957d4ab2abe68aaf4b68330048aa05215e#diff-68abffb26c82530feeba817384a6c848

Comment: there are other conditions as well that should work with and operatoe

Answer (score 2):

```
const userRepository = getRepository(User);
/* return userRepository.find({
    email: ILike("%" + body.search + "%")
}); */

return userRepository.find({
    where : [{
        email : ILike("%"+body.search+"%"),
    }, {
        fullName : ILike("%"+body.search+"%"),
    }]
});
```

In my case working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to write an OR clause using the simple typeorm `.find()` options:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md

Instead you'll have to use a QueryBuilder:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#adding-where-expression

This would look like

```
let results = await userRepo
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select()
  .where("firstname LIKE %:first%", { first: John })
  .orWhere("lastname LIKE %:last%", { last: Doe });
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that we can put where query in find-options as a string. I'm sticking to that. Thanks a lot though! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found that I can also put a 'string' query for where in TypeORM.

I tried this :

```
let results = await userRepo.find({
   where : `firstname LIKE '%john%' OR lastname LIKE '%doe%'`
})
```

Until the feature comes out, I'll have to stick with this.

Comment: This won't use the column aliases of your entity, so you'll have to transform them manually. Also it's prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: @EricJeker It was the only option at that point in the API. The new updates were rolled out  later.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const query.where = await getRepository(abc)
  .createQueryBuilder("abc")
  .select(); 
 await query.where("abc.Name ILIKE :Name", {
    Name: `%${searchTerm}%`,
  }).orWhere("abc.description ILIKE :description", {
    description: `%${searchTerm}%`,
  });`
```