# Typeorm Query Builder filtering multiple columns with one value

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

My aim is to hit api endpoint and only pass one query variable and try to filter out any of the columns based on single variable.

I have multiple users in database like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: 'test+1@test.com',
  username: 'test',
  phone_number: '+651231231',
  skillsets: 'Drawing, cooking',
  hobby: 'Sleeping',
},
{
  id: 2,
  email: 'test+2@test.com',
  username: 'test 2',
  phone_number: '+6512312311231',
  skillsets: 'Drawing, cooking',
  hobby: 'Drawing',
}
```

My function/Query

```
    let users = this.repo.createQueryBuilder('user');

    if (query && query !== '') {
      users = users
        .where('user.email like :email', { email: `%${query}%` })
        .orWhere('user.username like :username', {
          username: `%${query}%`,
        })
        .orWhere('user.phone_number like :phone_number', {
          phone_number: `%${query}%`,
        })
        .orWhere('user.skillsets like :skillsets', {
          phone_number: `%${query}%`,
        })
        .orWhere('user.hobby like :hobby', { hobby: `%${query}%` });
    }

    return users.getMany();
```

My api endpoint would be something like

```
/api/users?query=Sleeping
```

I can't filter by anything else other than email and I assumed is because of initial where but I am not entirely sure how to cater for this scenario.

I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to implement something similar and I found the answer in another [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814795/how-to-query-with-or-operation-in-where-object-using-find-options-api-in-typeo)

It is possible to use OR clause using the simple typeorm .find() options as described in [TypeORM docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md).
To query with OR operator you'll need to use an array of conditions instead of an object.

```
let users = await user.find({
    where: [
        { email: Like(%${query}%) },
        { skillsets: Like(%${query}%) },
        { username: Like(%${query}%) }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Just add the other columns.

```
users = users
        .where('user.email like :query AND (user.username like :query OR user.phone_number like :query)', { query: `%${query}%` })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setParameter` function from the query builder, and use the value wherever you pass the key of the parameter.
So maybe you can improve your code like this:

```
const users = this.repo.createQueryBuilder('user');

    if (query) {
      users
        .where('user.email LIKE :query')
        .orWhere('user.username LIKE :query')
        .orWhere('user.phone_number LIKE :query')
        .orWhere('user.skillsets LIKE :query')
        .orWhere('user.hobby LIKE :query')
        .setParameter('query', `%${query}%`);
    }

return users.getMany();
```

Hope this helps.